# How to pass $http data from Service to Controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-http

## AngularJS not working when I pass controller to the view

I have a problem and I can't troubleshoot it. In my simple app (very simple) I have a service that provides of users info. In angular I have an mvc which is trying to bind the info into the view.

The problem: when I pass the controller to the view, in the route directive, angular stops working in the view. I'm using a simple test {{1+1}} to verify if angular is working.

controller:

```
App.controller("loginController", function ($scope, usersModel) {

    $scope.users = usersModel.getUsers();

})
```

model

```
App.service("usersModel", function () {

    this.getUsers = function ($scope) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:50765/api/users");
    }});
```

Comment: what's the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service should inject the $http service and return the promise that it returns

```
App.service("usersModel", function ($http) {

    this.getUsers = function () {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:50765/api/users");
    }
});
```

And extract the data from the promise:

```
App.controller("loginController", function ($scope, usersModel) {

    var promise = usersModel.getUsers();
    promise.then(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
    });

})
```